# Unterschied zwischen Blumen und Blüten?

Tags: difference

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen "Blumen" und "Blüten"?

In Videos, z.B. über Bienen, höre ich beide Wörter, aber "Blüten" öfters. Gibt es einen feinen Unterschied?

Auf Englisch sagt man einfach "flowers".

Comment: Just to preempt close votes: I just looked up "Blume" in Wikipedia, and I learned something. It is not as trivial as I would have thought.

Comment: Und was ist mit *blossom*?

Comment: @CarstenS: Das Argument überzeugt mich nicht; das ist keine Sache des Sprachgebrauchs, sondern mit Nachschlagewerken beantwortbar.

Comment: With regard to @guidot's question, I think that "blossom" or "bloom" are equivalent as nouns to Blüten and as verbs to blühen. Both appear [to share a derivation](https://www.etymonline.com/word/blossom) with blühen via OE _blowan_.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Im Allgemeinen ist die Blume die ganze Pflanze, die *typischerweise* aus Blüte, Stengel, Blättern und Wurzel besteht (bei Schnittblumen auch ohne Wurzel). Eine Blüte ist nur der Kopf, in dem sich die Pflanzenteile für die Vermehrung befinden. Sie haben oft verschiedene Farben und Düfte, um Insekten, wie Bienen, für die Bestäubung anzulocken. Blüten gibt es aber nicht nur bei Blumen, sondern auch bei Bäumen und Sträuchern.

Answer (score 3):

[DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Bl%C3%BCte) schreibt bei Blüte:

> in mannigfaltigen Farben leuchtendes Fortpflanzungsorgan höherer Pflanzen, das sich aus einer Knospe voll entfaltet hat, Staubgefäße und Stempel enthält und in dem sich nach der Befruchtung die Samen entwickeln

Damit ist klar, dass Blüten auch anderswo vorkommen, nämlich bei Bäumen.

Answer (score 2):

"Blüte" (blossom/bloom) is the upper part (petal etc.) of many "Blumen" (flower), which is the whole plant, but also other plants can have "Blüten".

Comment: I think that this describes everyday usage well, but not necessarily the technical meaning of these words in biology.

Comment: To you have a source for that? I'm a native speaker and I don't consider these meanings colloquial.

Comment: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blume

Comment: I looked this up as well, but I would like to have an official source. This article is not that  enlightening in my opinion.

Comment: I agree with Carsten. The details are worked out in a branch of biology, i.e. botany. @shaedrich: Every undergrad botany book will cover the details usually, e.g. check Botanik by Lüttge, Kluge, Bauer (Wiley VCH).

Comment: Die Diskussion ist müßig. Standardmäßig gehen wir hier von Alltagssprache aus, sofern in der Frage nicht explizit nach Fachausdrücken gefragt wurde. Wenn wir hier zu lamentieren anfangen, in der Botanik sei das aber so und so, dann müssten wir das bei anderen Fragen ebenso machen.